# if statement for dictionary objectforkey:@"key" when value is <null>

Tags: objective-c

I am working with objective c for an iphone app.

I see that `[dictionary objectForKey:@"key"]` return `<null>`.  Doing a `if([dictionary objectForKey:@"key"] == nil || [dictionary objectForKey:@"key"] == null)` does not seem to catch this case.

Doing a `if([[dictionary objectForKey:@"key"] isEqualToString:@"<null>"])` causes my program to crash.

What is the correct expression to catch `<null>`?

**More Details**
An if statement for nil still isn't catching the case... Maybe i'm just too tired to see something, but here's additional info:

Dictionary is populated via a url that contains json data like so:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:"http://site.com/"];

dataresult = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

NSError *error;
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataresult options:kNilOptions error:&    error];
```

doing an NSLog on the dictionary gives this output:

```
{
    key = "<null>";
    responseMessage = "The email / registration code combination is incorrect";
}
```

Comment: sorry my mistake, i changed it to dictionaries...i'm very very tired right now

Comment: Hmmm... now that I'm looking a little more closely at your question, you *are* looking for nil already in your "if" case.  If you do something like "`id something = [dictionary objectForKey: @"key"];`" in your code and set a debugging breakpoint there, is *something* something or is it nil?

Comment: the output of something is `<null>`.  The json feed was generated by a php website.  Does that make a difference?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have an instance of `NSNull`. Actually, *the* instance, since it's a singleton.

Cocoa collections can't contain `nil`, although they may return `nil` if you try to access something which isn't present.

However, sometimes it's valuable for a program to store a thing meaning "nothing" in a collection. That's what `NSNull` is for.

As it happens, JSON can represent null objects. So, when converting JSON to a Cocoa collection, those null objects get translated into the `NSNull` object.

When Cocoa formats a string with a "%@" specifier, a `nil` value will get formatted as "(null)" with parentheses.  An `NSNull` value will get formatted as "<null>" with angle brackets.

Comment: WOOO HOOOOO!!!!!! It is the NSNull! now my if statement looks so beautiful `if([fullDataArray objectForKey:@"key"] == nil || [fullDataArray objectForKey:@"key"] == NULL || [[fullDataArray objectForKey:@"key"] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) { /* Look, i'm in!  Now sleeping time */}`

Comment: `nil` and `NULL` are equivalent, so you don't need to check for equality with both; and you can just say `if([fullDataArray objectForKey:@"key"] || ...`.

Comment: @echristopherson, you mean `if (![fullDataArray objectForKey:@"key"] || ...` with a NOT operator ("!"), to match John's condition where he's checking for equality to `nil`/`NULL`.

Answer (score 3):

New answer:

Thanks for adding the detail.  It looks like the "`dataresult`" you are setting is ***not*** a JSON object so no wonder you're getting wacky results from putting a raw string into "`[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:]`.  You may need to do some basic error checking on your data before you call anything JSON related.

Original answer:

First off, if this were my code, I wouldn't name a "`NSDictionary`" object "`array`" (and I see you caught my comment in your edit... hope you get some sleep soon!).

Secondly, what you are looking for is "`nil`", not a string named "`<null>`".  As [Apple's documentation for `objectForKey:` states](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDictionary/objectForKey%3a), if an object is not found for the key you are asking for, a nil is returned.  The Xcode console tries to be helpful in converting nil objects to "`<null>`" strings in it's output.

Do "`if [dictionary objectForKey: @"key"] != nil`" and you should be happier.

Comment: But the php script did a json_encode($array) to output contents.  Form my objetive C code, i ahve no problem accessing any of the other key value pairs fmro the dictionary.  are you sure this is not a json object?

Comment: Just for giggles, convert the `NSData` object into a `NSString` (or simply retrieve the data from the URL via `[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:]`) and `NSLog` it out to see if it looks like JSON to you.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the following code:

```
if ([[dictionary valueForKey:@"key"] isKindOfClass:[NSNull Class]]{
   //This means that the value inside the dictionary is <null>
}
else{
//the value is not <null>
}
```

This should do it.